# popup php command on window.closed

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, popup

I am trying to write a simple programm, that will have a button.

- When I click the button it will open up a popup window.
- When I close the popup I want my parent page to be reloaded
- After the window is closed, I want the parent page to know, that the child was closed, so it should print some message.

I tried to implement this setting a cookie in the js function and reading it in the php. Unfortunaly as soon as I close the window once, I always get the print message, when I reload the page. Here is my code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {
    unset($_COOKIE['cookie']);
    setcookie("cookie", "", time()-3600, "/");
    echo "window closed";
}
?>
<script>
    function popup() {

        var win = window.open("", "Page Title", "toolbar=no, location=no");
        var win_timer = setInterval(function() {
            if(win.closed) {
                window.location.reload();
                clearInterval(win_timer);
                document.cookie = "cookie=cookieValue";
            }
        }, 100);
    }
</script>
<input type="button" value="Open popup" onclick="javascript: return popup()" />
```

Comment: I see no php within your Javascript, please update your title, its misleading.

Comment: As You say it, I realised the same. I hope this title fits better.

Comment: I also have to admin, that if someone has a different way to solve this problem (without using cookies) I would be very pleased as well :)